# what is wrong with this piece of code? html + php

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

i've a simple function, which has two parameters, one for the image url, and other for the attributes for the image

```
function image_found($url,$attributes)
{
    if(@getimagesize($url))
    {
        echo '<img src="'.$url.'" '.$attributes.'/>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<img src="'.base_url().'/site_images/image_not_found.svg" '.$attributes.'/>';
    }
}
```

now what i'm trying to do is create a clickable image, if the image is found, now this is the html code

```
echo '<div class="panel-body">';
echo '<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 text-center">';
$url = base_url().'product_images/'.$result->product_image.'.'.$result->image_type;
$attributes = 'height="200px" width="100%"';
echo '<a href="product.com/full/url">'.image_found($url,$attributes).'</a>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
```

and this is the output i'm getting

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
        <img src="http://localhost/nsc/product_images/7908076366784972032090.jpg" height="200px" width="100%"/>
        <a href="#"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

i don't know what is wrong here, i'm using bootstrap

Comment: Use `return` instead of `echo` inside your function.

Comment: Are you sure this is the output you're getting? The output is not congruent with your `echo`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use return statements instead of echo in your function and your problem should be solved ;-)

Answer (score 0):

When you need to return a value from a function, use `return` statement instead of `echo`

When `echo` is used the output immediately gets printed instead of getting returned to the place where the function call is. Here is an illustration.

```
function printer(){
    echo 'second';  
}

echo 'first'.' '.printer().' '.'last';
```

The Output:

```
secondfirst  last
```

This is the exact same thing happening with your code. The echo in `image_found()` gets printed as

```
<img src="http://localhost/nsc/product_images/7908076366784972032090.jpg" height="200px" width="100%"/>
```

The rest of the echo statement gets printed as

```
<a href="#"></a>
```

So using a return statement should solve your problem

Comment: using @ is bad, you should use try catch blocks. its not good to simply hide an error when we know there will be one

Answer (score 0):

The better way is verify if your image exists (remove @) and then return (instead of echo):

```
...

if(file_exists('your/path/to/image'))
    return '<img src="'.$url.'" '.$attributes.'/>';
else
    return '<img src="'.base_url().'/site_images/image_not_found.svg" '.$attributes.'/>' 

...
```

Comment: what is the use of @?

Comment: You're using "@" (@getimagesize($url) to hide any warning which should display, so I think it's better you check if the file really exists and then, do whatever you want...